# 2 Factor Authentication for Mobile Application

Tags: android, authentication, mobile

Is there any 2-Factor Authentication technique (which is not depends on external devices like security tokens) like Key Stock based, is available for the mobile platform like Android? Any reference to commercial solution provider is also helpful.

**NOTE:** I am not looking for application, which generate 2-nd Key.

Comment: I found the tick mark and accepted. Thanks for educating me :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, *SecureAuth* has developed 2 Factor authentication access on the Android platform, still in beta though

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b22-nHr9gX0

http://blog.gosecureauth.com/blog/2-factor-application-access-for-android-honeycomb-testing

Comment: Thanks Chris. I gone thu the link. But unable to get the complete picture. Can you give some more info on this?

Answer (score 1):

SecureAuth also recently had a webinar regarding their Android solution which may answer some of your questions.

http://www.gosecureauth.com/news-events/webinar-detail.aspx?ID=48

Note: I would have responded to Chris's answer but could not.  Sorry.